# use an cicle for to add content to an linkedList java

Tags: java, arrays, list

i have this script, but i can't increment

```
    LinkedList<Card> deckOfCards = new LinkedList<Card>();

    for (int count = 0; count < deckOfCards.size(); count++) { 
        deckOfCards[count].add(new Card(Rank.values()[count % 13].toString(),Suit.values()[count / 13].toString(), number[count % 13],Image[count % 52]));

    }
```

i get an error on  deckOfCards[count], so my doubt is how i can do this 
(The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to LinkedList)

i previous code is an array, and works

```
deckOfCards = new Card[number_cards];

    for (int count = 0; count < deckOfCards.length; count++) { 
        deckOfCards[count] = new Card(Rank.values()[count % 13].toString(),Suit.values()[count / 13].toString(), number[count % 13],Image[count % 52]);
    }
}


//suppose to get na name, value of card, but the result is [null, null, null, etc]
public Card[] giveCardPlayer1() {

    String name1 = Arrays.toString(deckOfCards);
    nameF = name1;
    String suit_1 = deckOfCards.toString();
    suit1 = suit_1;
    return deckOfCards;

}


public int totalValuePlayer1() {
    return currentTotal1;
}

public String name1() {
    return nameF;
}

public String suit_1() {
    return suit1;
}
```

thanks!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Just call `deckOfCards.add(...)`.

You can't index a Java `List` the same way you would an array. You have to use its [`add()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29) method instead. This appends the specified element to the end of the list.

There is also [another `add()` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29) which takes an `int index` parameter. However, since lists are not of fixed size, you can't just directly set the n<sup>th</sup> element of the list by calling `deckOfCards.add(count, new Card(...))` - you need to ensure first that the specified element exists in the list, otherwise you get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. It is also worth mentioning that accessing linked lists by index is a slow operation (compared to e.g. `ArrayList`s) for any list of nontrivial size.

#### Update

Ah, and you need to fix your loop invariant too. The current version

```
for (int count = 0; count < deckOfCards.size(); count++) { ...
```

will never execute the loop body, since the initial size of your list is 0. Change it to

```
for (int count = 0; count < number_cards; count++) { ...
```

Comment: but if i do deckOfCards.add(...) cycle is not done, is not increment, and the result is [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, etc]

Comment: @user455318, that is due to your incorrect loop invariant; see my update.

Comment: the result is the same [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, etc], i update my post

Comment: @user455318, what is the value of `number_cards`? Can you put a print statement inside the loop to check how many times it is actually executed?

Comment: number_cards = 52; and i put a print and is shown 52 lines of specific Sysout. So, the problem is another, what reason is the result null, 52 times?

Comment: i think the problem is that deckOfCards[count] is needed to create each suit of cards, if is not present, the [count % 13] for example is null

Comment: @user455318, if you have 52 `null` values printed out, obviously you have added *something* to your list. `new Card(...)` must produce either a `Card` object or an exception, but in the latter case your loop would be interrupted (since it contains no exception handling). So my suspicion is that the problem is either in the initialization of your `Card` instances or in the way you print them out. Try assigning the new `Card` to a variable and print out its properties before adding it to the list. Also, please post the code you use to print out the contents of the list.

Comment: this line get the name of all cards and print  String name1 = Arrays.toString(deckOfCards);, possible error here

Comment: @user455318, that is unsuitable for printing a `List`. Try simply `String name1 = deckOfCards.toString()`. And if you have implemented `Card.toString()`, please post that code too.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Peter's post; if you need to index a list like you try to do here, you can use [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead.